# Angular *ngIf for nested formgroup value

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to implement *ngIf for some div...

Doesn't work:

```
*ngIf="postForm.value.osnovne.sekcija === vozila"
```

also

```
*ngIf="postForm.controls['osnovne'].value.sekcija === vozila
```

This is my form:

```
this.postForm = this.fb.group({
      osnovne: this.fb.group({
        sekcija: vozila,
        cena: "",
        dogovor: "",
        opis: ""
      }),
      detaljne: this.fb.group({
        name: "",
        value: ""
      }),
      imagePath: this.fb.group({
        data: ""
      })
    });
```

How to to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `.get()` better, something like this:

`*ngIf="postForm.get('osnovne').get('sekcija').value === vozila"`

`.get()` will insure you will always get the value even if the Control is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Using [ngx-sub-form](https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form) library it'd be easier to break down your form into sub form components and it'd look like the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <app-osnovne-form [formControlName]="formControlNames.osnovne"></app-osnovne-form>
</form>

<div *ngIf="formGroupValues.osnovne?.sekcija === 'vozila'; else noVozila">
  "vozila" is the current value of osnovne.sekcija
</div>

<ng-template #noVozila>
  "vozila" is not the current value of osnovne.sekcija
</ng-template>

<pre>{{ formGroupValues | json }}</pre>
```

[image]

[image]

Here's a live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-answer-angular-ngif-for-nested-formgroup-value?file=src/app/form/form.component.html

**Edit:**

If you want to go further, I've just published a blog post to explain a lot of things about forms and ngx-sub-form here https://dev.to/maxime1992/building-scalable-robust-and-type-safe-forms-with-angular-3nf9